# Editorconfig Const/Enum Settings Not Working in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, constants, editorconfig

I have a single .editorconfig file in a root directory that applies to all of my Visual Studio projects.  It contains the following rules:

```
# Const field naming rules
dotnet_naming_symbols.const_fields.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.const_fields.required_modifiers = const
dotnet_naming_rule.const_fields.symbols = const_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.const_fields.style = all_upper
dotnet_naming_rule.const_fields.severity = warning

# Enum naming rules
dotnet_naming_symbols.enums.applicable_kinds = enum
dotnet_naming_rule.enums.symbols = enums
dotnet_naming_rule.enums.style = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.enums.severity = warning

# Naming Styles
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.all_upper.capitalization = all_upper
```

According to the [EditorConfig docs](http://editorconfig.org/)

> EditorConfig files are read top to bottom and the closest EditorConfig files are read last. Properties from matching EditorConfig sections are applied in the order they were read, so properties in closer files take precedence.

By that reasoning, my `enums` rules should "take precedence" over my `const_fields` rules.  However, the following enum declaration continues to give me a warning:

```
public enum AggregationMode {
    Simultaneous,
    Sequential,
}
```

Saying: `Warning IDE1006 Naming rule violation: These words cannot contain lower case characters`.

Are enum values treated as const by the compiler?  I have tried closing/reopening my code file in VS, reordering the const/enum sections of the .editorconfig, building/rebuilding my solution, and even restarting VS, but the warning won't go away.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Enums are a [value data type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm).

Comment: @DiskCrasher  what does that have to do with .editorconfig?

Comment: He asked if enums were treated as a const. I'm not sure how .editorconfig would handle this, but some quick testing would confirm.

Comment: @DiskCrasher well I already performed all those tests mentioned at the end of my question.  What additional tests could I do to see what editorconfig is doing with my naming rules?

Comment: My guess is that you can't define rules for enums. If you change `dotnet_naming_rule.const_fields.style = pascal_case` do you still get the error for your enums?

Comment: @DiskCrasher  We definitely can set rules for enums.  One of the available values for `dotnet_naming_symbols..applicable_kinds` is `enum`, as seen in the IntelliSense for the .editorconfig VS Extension and in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kuhlenh/50fdabc40918255747c156cc1412f491) by a Microsoft employee.  And yes, it seems like whatever rules I apply to `const` end up being used by `enum`s, which is annoying because I want `const` fields in all caps and `enum`s in Pascal case

Comment: @Rabadash8820 I have the same problem in my .editorconfig. I'd be interested in your solution. Did you find one?

Comment: @PhilippGrathwohl  My solution was to weep softly with a bottle of wine.  I did come across this Microsoft Docs [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference) though, which seems to serve as the official reference for .NET .editorconfig settings.  My next step will probably be to open an issue at the [dotnet/roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) GitHub repo.

Comment: Well, a month later I have finally posted an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24209) at the Roslyn repo :P  I doubt it will be a very high-priority item, but we shall see